# Can I configure Poltergeist/Capybara to point at PhantomJS in a Docker container?

Tags: docker, poltergeist

If I have the PhantomJS Docker container running, is it possible to use Poltergeist to run the tests against this container, using it as a remote PhantomJS server?

Comment: Did you have Capybara with Poltergeist + Phantomjs running in a single container? I'm having trouble configuring it and there's almost no help online - wondered if you ran into any similar difficulties?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't do yet, but I guess you can ;-)

I would do as follow:

1. create your "custom" phantomjs `docker image` (for inspiration you can see how the others do this):

   - start your phantomjs with the flag `--webdriver` [ [references](http://phantomjs.org/api/command-line.html) ]
   - expose the phantomjs http-port (so you can communicate to this container through this port)
2. Configure your capybara tests with the address of your container:

```
    Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
      Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, options)
    end
```

where in the options, you can provide the `:port` option defined in "(1)" [ [references](https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist#customization) ]

Btw I don't found yet where you can put the `docker-container-ip` on this configuration.